# Convert alphanumeric phone numbers with letters into numbers

Tags: python, string

I have an assignment where we have to convert alphanumeric phone numbers into just numbers. For example `"555-PLS-HELP"` should convert into `"555-757-4357"`. I wrote some of it but it keeps giving me incorrect output.

```
alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num = '22233344455566677778889999'

phone_number = str(input("Please enter a phone number: "))

counter = len(phone_number[:4])
total = phone_number[:4]
while counter > 0:
    alpha = phone_number[-counter]
    if alpha.isalpha():
        total += num[alph.index(alpha)]
    else:
        total += alpha
    counter -= 1
print(total)
```

I keep getting weird output.

For example:

```
Please enter a phone number: '555-PLS-HELP'
```

Gives:

```
555-4357
```

Comment: Any cases (inputs and the weird outputs you got for them)?

Comment: The program runs fine until the output. For example if i input 555-PLS-HELP the output is 555-4357. Then I changed it to len(phone_number[:8]) and total = phone_number[:8] and it gives me the output 555-PLS-757-4357

Comment: You should ask yourself, what am I trying to accomplish here with `counter` and `total`, `[:4]`, `[-counter]`, etc?  Why did the answers provided below lack those variables?  How are they different?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to consider in your code:

1. Changing your first slice to `counter = len(phone_number[4:])` produces a working solution: you'd like to iterate for the length of the *rest* of the number rather than the length of the area code prefix.
2. A simple `for n in phone_number` is preferable to taking `len()` and iterating using a counter variable and indexing from the rear with `-counter`, which is non-intuitive.
3. `input()` returns a `str`; there's no need for a superfluous cast.

This is a perfect situation for a dictionary data structure, which maps keys to values and is an [explicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) version of what you're already doing. Use `zip` to combine your strings into a dictionary.

In the list comprehension, each character is looked up in the `keypad` dictionary and its corresponding entry is returned. Using the `dict.get(key, default)` method, any items not present in the dictionary will be `default`.

```
alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num = '22233344455566677778889999'
keypad = dict(zip(alph, num))

phone_number = input("Please enter a phone number: ")

print("".join([keypad.get(x, x) for x in phone_number]))
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/TubbyJadedProtools)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num = '22233344455566677778889999'
# converts the above lists into a dict
lookup = dict(zip(alph, num))

phone_number = input("Please enter a phone number: ")

result = ''
for c in phone_number:
    # if needs changing
    if c.isalpha():
        result += lookup[c.upper()]
    # simply append otherwise
    else:
        result += c

print(result)
```

Result:

```
Please enter a phone number: 555-PLS-HELP
```

Output:

```
555-757-4357
```

Comment: Love this answer, but it needs a lot of explanation .  It'd be preferable to hard code an input and show the corresponding output as well.  There's already a test case in the question.

Comment: Changed to include the test case.

Answer (score 1):

```
alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num = '22233344455566677778889999'

phone_number = str(input("Please enter a phone number: "))

counter = len(phone_number)
total = ''
while counter > 0:
    alpha = phone_number[-counter]
    if alpha.isalpha():
        total += num[alph.index(alpha)]
    else:
        total += alpha
    counter -= 1
print(total)
```

Test:

```
Please enter a phone number: '555-PLS-HELP'
```

Output:

```
555-757-4357
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate through the inputted number, check if it's alphabet and get the corresponding number if so, all in one-line:

```
alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num = '22233344455566677778889999'

phone_number = input("Please enter a phone number: ")

print(''.join([num[alph.index(x.upper())] if x.isalpha() else x for x in phone_number]))
```

**Sample run**:

```
Please enter a phone number: 555-PLS-HELP
555-757-4357
```

If it's an alphabet, this gets the index of the alphabet from `alph` and use that to look up in the `num` to get corresponding number. In the else case, just copies the number.

Comment: Nice, but lacking any explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are considering only last 4 characters of an a-priori unknown string? You could search first if phone_number has some alphabetic characters, and if it does, then starting from the first occurrence of such an alphabetic character you can replace it with the correct digit. This works for capital letters:

```
alph = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num = '22233344455566677778889999'

phone_number = raw_input("Please enter a phone number: ")


def fstAlpha(string):
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[i].isalpha():
            return i
return -1

index = fstAlpha(phone_number);

if index != -1:
    for i in range(index,len(phone_number)):
        if(phone_number[i].isalpha()):
            to_replace = phone_number[i]
            replace_with = num[alph.index(to_replace)]
            phone_number = phone_number.replace(to_replace,replace_with)
print phone_number
```